# Use mobilenet V1 model on Android

Tags: android, tensorflow

I'm trying to use the model used on [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb) tutorial in an Android app. I wanted to modify DetectorActivity.java and TensorFlowMultiBoxDetector.java found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo) but it seems like i miss some parameters as *imageMean*, *imageStd*, *inputName*, *outputLocationsName* and *outputScoresName*.

From what I understand, input name is the name of the input for the model and both outputs are the names for the position and score output, but what do *imageMean* and *imageStd* stand for ?

I don't need to use the model with a camera, I just need to detect objects on bitmaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding of input/output names seems correct. They are tensorflow node names that can receive input and will contain the outputs at the end. `imageMean` and `imageStd` are used to scale the RGB values of the image to the mean of 0 and the standard deviation of 1. See the 8 lines starting from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo/TensorFlowMultiBoxDetector.java#L208

Answer (score 0):

The TensorFlow android demo app you are referring to has been updated. It now supports MobileNets. Check it out at github: commit [53aabd5cb0ffcc1fd33cbd00eb468dd8d8353df2](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/53aabd5cb0ffcc1fd33cbd00eb468dd8d8353df2).

Comment: If you don't want answers to be deleted you have to make sure the answer has value without the link. Check it out at *some other place* is simply not appreciated and you got two comments to that extent under your deleted answer.  I've also removed the complaint form your answer. Those should be discussed at [meta].